# Netsuite File cabinet

Tags: java, javascript, netsuite

I was wondering if it would be possible to use nlapiLoadFile() to call a file from an external drive in the server (A server within the company or local drive) and not from the file cabinet. (which the file has to be uploaded manually)? So I can use it to import the file using nlapiCreateCSVImport().

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No. You could use nlapiRequestURL, which has to be accessible from the external server.

Comment: How would I use that to import a csv file from a vault . Would it be something like nlapiREquestURL(....//server12/forler12321/1.csv) . Then do i need to request for response ? Thanks for our help

Comment: @Jamesguilford you'll get a response object from which you have to extract the body property, which is the csv itself (see nlresponseobj on the help files). Then you need to find a parser to transform the response body string into a JSON object -- search on github. From there it's pure JS. Also now that I notice your drive is local, you have to make this document web-available as the NetSuite server can't see your local network.. put it in an ftp server or something.

Comment: Interesting...then How would i transform back JSON to CSV for import?@pipechang

Comment: @Jamesguilford try this https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv it's a node library but of course can be used as plain js.

Answer (score 0):

@pipechang Here's what I got so far, I can't quite understand it when U say I need to convert the body of the message to JSON
What If I pull in the file as XML, then do i still need to convert it to JSON when I read the body ? If not, how would i then be able to transform it into a CSV later on?/

Thanks for your help.

```
    function scheduledimporting(type){

    var csvMap = '15'; //saved CSV import id
    //var csvFile = nlapiLoadFile("5828"); //csv file id from filecabinet                
    var urlrequest=nLapiRequestURL('https://...........',null,a);
    var body=response.getBody(); //get the body of the message 
    var csvImport = nlapiCreateCSVImport();//creating a new csv import

    /***
    If the file that I'm pulling in is a CSV, would i get the body as CSV?
    DO I still need to go through Prsing the body and transform it to JSON Object
    If I do, how would I transfer it back to CSV ? 
    ***/
    csvImport.setMapping(csvMap);//setting import map
    csvImport.setPrimaryFile(body.getValue());//file to be imported
    csvImport.setOption("jobName", "Test1111");//setting job status' job name       
    var csvSubmitId = nlapiSubmitCSVImport(csvImport);//submitting the CSV
}
```

Comment: You can run your function content in Netsuite's Script Debugger.
https://system.netsuite.com/app/common/scripting/scriptdebugger.nl